# Which WiFi frames are MAC Address Randomized?

Tags: wifi

Besides Probe Requests,

which are the other WiFi Mgmt frames that have MAC Address Randomization ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Probe request -> Probe response
2. android wifi connection
   https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization
   "cause the device to use a randomized MAC address when connecting to a Wi-Fi network."
   which means AUTH / ASSOC Req / ASSOC response use mac randomization also